# How to prove that a set of polynomials spans a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

Let $V_n$ denote the vector space of polynomials of degree at most $n$ over a field $F$, and suppose $\{f_0, f_1, \cdots, f_{n-1}, f_n\}$ is a set of polynomials such that for all $j$ between $0$ and $n$, we have that $f_j$ has degree $j$. Show that the $\{f_j\}$ form a basis for $V_n$.

Let $B = \{f_0, f_1, \cdots, f_{n-1}, f_n\}$. We want to show that $B$ is linearly independent and spans $V_n$.
For linear independence, suppose $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_if_i = \sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i(\sum_{j=0}^{i}a_{ij}x^j) = \sum_{i=0}^{n}(\sum_{j=0}^{i}a_ia_{ij}x^j) = \sum_{j=0}^{n}(\sum_{i=j}^{n}a_ia_{ij})x^j = 0$$ Then, $\sum_{i=j}^{n}a_ia_{ij} = 0$ for all $j$. Specifically, for $j=n$, $a_na_{nn} = 0$. $a_{nn}$ cannot be 0 since $x^j$ for $j=n$ must be of degree $n$, and so $a_n = 0$. Thus, we can rewrite as $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_if_i = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_if_i +a_{n}f_n = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_if_i + 0 =   \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(\sum_{i=j}^{n-1}a_ia_{ij})x^j = 0$$ We do the same process for $j = n-1$ to conclude that $a_{n-1}=0$ until $j=0$. Thus, $a_i=0$ for all $i$, and so $B$ is linear independent.

For spanning ...

EDIT: Attached below is answer key's proof, though I'm a bit confused by it.
[image]

Comment: You don't really need to show spanning. Once you have $n$ linearly independent vectors, you're done. Though this assumes you already know the dimension of $V_n$ is $n$.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow Why? I thought basis requires linear independence + spanning? Even if I don't need to show spanning, how could I show it?

Comment: So the reasoning is, if you have $n$ linearly independent vectors, they span a subspace of dimension $n$. But the dimension of $V_n$ *is* $n$, so this subspace must be all of $V_n$. Like I said, this assumes you know that the dimension of $V_n$ is $n+1$.

Comment: And sorry, I meant the dimension of $V_n$ is $n+1$.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow Ah, I see, thank you! I just updated the post w/ the solution's proof. Can you explain the proof technique? I'm a bit confused by it.

Comment: Again, I think it's easier to avoid showing spanning directly. But if you really want to know what's going on in that solution, the idea is to pick an arbitrary polynomial, and show that you can subtract off multiples of the $f_i$ until you get zero. This shows every polynomial is a linear combination of the $f_i$, hence they span.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow Great, thank you! I just wanted to understand both ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\dim V_n=n+1$ and since $B$ has $n+1$ linearly independent vectors, $B$ spans $V_n$.

This has nothing to do with your specific situation. If $V$ is a $n$-dimensional vector space over some field $F$ and if $S\subset V$ is a set with $n$ elements, then the following assertions are equivalent:

- $\operatorname{span}(S)=V$;
- $S$ is linearly independent;
- $S$ is a basis of $V$.

Comment: To expand upon this, suppose the OP does not already know $\dim V_n=n+1$. Then you can show that $\{1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^n\}$ is a basis for $V_n$ (much easier) which establishes $\dim V_n=n+1$.

Comment: Indeed. That's a nice remark.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you very much! That was very helpful!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.